# Taking average of numbers in a one dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I am currently working on an assignment for my Prog 2 class that involves creating a class Movie that needs to store ratings in an array and take the average of the ratings. I've gotten most of the program done but I'm having trouble figuring out why my averages are not printing out correctly, I just keep on getting the same value.

In addition, rather than having a number display after "Avg. Viewer Rating", I would like it to say a word. For example, an average of 1 would be "Terrible", 2 would be "Bad", 3 would be "Okay", 4 would be "Good", 5 would be "Great".

I am fairly new to C++ so any guidance would be wonderful. Thank you!

My class declaration:

```
class Movie {

private:
    int rate[5];
    int ratings;
    string movie;
    string userRate[5] = {"Terrible","Bad","Okay","Good","Great"};
    string mpaa;

public:
    Movie();
    Movie(string title, string mpaaRating);
    void setMPAA(string mpaaRating);
    double getAverage();
    void addRating(int rating);
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream &out, Movie &M);
};
```

getAverage() function:

```
double Movie::getAverage()
{
    int total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        total += rate[i] * (i+1);
        ratings++;
    }


    if (ratings > 0)
        return total / ratings;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

main:

```
int main() {

    Movie A("Inception","PG-13");
    Movie B("Fear and Loathing in Las Vegas","PG-13");

    A.addRating(1);
    A.addRating(3);
    A.addRating(5);
    A.addRating(5);
    A.addRating(5);

    B.addRating(3);
    B.addRating(2);
    B.addRating(1);
    B.addRating(4);
    B.addRating(5);

    cout << A << endl;
    cout << B << endl;
}
```

And **OUTPUT**

```
Movie: Inception
MPAA Rating: PG-13
Avg. Viewer Rating: 3

Movie: Fear and Loathing in Las Vegas
MPAA Rating: PG-13
Avg. Viewer Rating: 3
```

Comment: Why `* (i+1);`? Also, where's the implementation of `<<`? Have you done any debugging? There's many things they could be wrong, and you haven't included enough code to help your narrow it down.

Comment: You have posted bits and pieces of code. It will be better in you can post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Because you are performing integer division. You should convert variables to float first. So change:

```
return total / ratings;
```

to:

```
return float(total) / float(ratings);
```

Comment: I don't think that will solve it. The first movie had a total rating of 19. 19 / 5 = 6.334. Integer division wouldn't cause that to become 3.

Comment: It did solve it! 19 / 5 is 3.8. I changed them to convert to double and it works!

Comment: @DaneWind Whoops, dur. Typed it into the calculator wrong then didn't think about the result. My bad.

Comment: Its okay :) @Carcigenicate